# Microsoft Excel | Inserting a Formula in Filtered Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some very large spreadsheets, in which information I need is spread across several. I have a master spreadsheet which is "pulling" information from those various sheets using VLOOKUP. However, everytime I go to change the Table Array in the formula, then drag the formula down it overwrites the cells I filter out because they have information in the them already. I have drawn up an example for simplicity sake, see below.

[image: Example of Spreadsheet]

What I would do, is filter everything but the cells with #N/A and apply a new VLOOKUP to the next workbook, in an attempt to narrow down the list of items I don't have information for. But when I drag from C5 to C8 the formula is changed in C6 & C7 as well.

[image: Example of Filtered Spreadsheet]

In short - how do I apply a moderately different formula between filtered cells without effecting the hidden ones? Or is there a better way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula for the whole column to something of the form:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP1),VLOOKUP2,VLOOKUP1)
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how many "subset" VLOOKUPs I can use there are about a dozen workbooks all with different information

Comment: Are all the reference tables in the same structure? If so, an option would be to use PowerQuery to append them all together (with a "File name" column) so that you can lookup against a single table. You are only limited by the limit to nested IF statements, as described here: https://exceljet.net/nested-ifs

If you have the more recent version of Excel, then get round that by using the IFS function, described here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-ifs-function

Comment: No unfortunately they are not. Or I would just use the PowerQuery as you suggested.